# In node.js why was EventEmitter included in events as a circular reference?

Tags: node.js

The following code shows the contents of the `events` object.

```
const events = require('events');
console.log(events);
```

The output is,

```
{ [Function: EventEmitter]
  EventEmitter: [Circular],
  usingDomains: false,
  defaultMaxListeners: [Getter/Setter],
  init: [Function],
  listenerCount: [Function] }
```

There must be a benefit to using a circular reference for `EventEmitter` and not the rest but I'm not sure what it is.  Why did they construct the `events` object using this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There must be a benefit to using a circular reference for `EventEmitter`

It was probably done for backwards compatibility.

Documentation for the `events` module wayyyy back suggests it was the only way to import `EventEmitter`.

["To access the EventEmitter class, `require('events').EventEmitter`"](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter)